# C program: pointer and pointer of string

Tags: c, pointers

This is the code that make me confused.

```
static char *s[] = {"black", "white", "pink", "violet"};
char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1, s}, ***p;
p = ptr; // p point to the address of (s+3), so "violet"
++p;     // p point to "pink"
printf("%s", **p+1); // I though it print "pink" but answer is "ink", I'm not sure about the sequence of ** and +, which executes first and how is this one begins from "i"?
```

Comment: To be sure about sequence/precedence order of operators in C. Look for "Operator Precedence in C" on Google

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. "This is the code that make me confused." is not a question.

Comment: @sashoalm The comment on the last line makes it quite clear and is in the form of a question.

Comment: @JimBalter I didn't look for questions in the code block. I don't think they should be written there.

Comment: @sashoalm That's no excuse for claiming that what is quite clear is not clear. If you feel the need to set rules as to how people are allowed to clarify their question, go to meta. The fact is that it is irresponsible to not read the entire question before commenting or answering. And I can show you plenty of questions by experienced SO users that use comments to identify the points of confusion.

Comment: @JimBalter I assure you, I had not spotted the question that was inside a comment in the code block. Trust me, it can happen. People don't expect to find the question there. At least I don't. While I was writing my comment, I did not know there was a question inside the comments inside the code block. I hope I wasn't unclear.

Comment: @sashoalm So you have weaknesses and limitations and you don't bother to read questions before commenting -- that's no one else's fault. I never said that you *did* spot it -- I clearly noted your irresponsibility in *not* reading the code -- so I have no idea why you're whinging about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static char *s[] = {"black", "white", "pink", "violet"};
```

The above statement defines `s` to be an array of characters and initializes its elements with  pointers to the first element of the string literals enclosed in braces. `static` means the array `s` has internal linkage and its lifetime extends across the entire program run.

```
char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1, s}, ***p;
```

The above statement defines `ptr` to be an array of objects of type `char **`, i.e., pointer to pointer to characters. It also defines `p` of type `char ***`, i.e., a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a character. It initializes `ptr` with pointers to elements of the array `s`.

Therefore, `ptr[0]` points to `s[3]`, `ptr[1]` points to `s[2]` and so on. The below two statements are equivalent. This is because the array `ptr` decays (evaluates) to a pointer to its first element.

```
p = ptr;
// the above is equivalent to
p = &ptr[0];

++p;  //  makes p point to the next element of ptr
```

The side effect of executing the above statement is to increment `p`, i.e., make it point to the next element which is `ptr[1]`.

```
**p+1
```

Indirection operator `*` has higher precedence. Therefore, `**p` is evaluated first. Since `p` is pointing to `ptr[1]`, `*p` evaluates to `ptr[1]`. Now `ptr[1]` is pointing to `s[2]`, therefore `**p` evaluates to `s[2]`. `s[2]` is pointing to the first element of the string literal `"pink"`. This means `**p + 1` points to the next element, i.e, 2nd element which is `'i'`.

```
printf("%s", **p + 1); // prints ink
// equivalent to
printf("%s", "pink" + 1); // prints ink
// equivalent to
printf("%s", &"pink"[1]); // prints ink
```

Answer (score 1):

After `++p`, `p` does not point to "pink". It points to `ptr[1]`, and `ptr[1]` points to `s[2]`, and `s[2]` points to the first character of "pink".

`*p` is `ptr[1]`, and `**p` is `s[2]`.  So `**p + 1` is `&s[2][1]`, i.e. the "i" in "pink".

It is like:

```
char *ptr = **p;   // ptr points to the 'p' in "pink"
printf("%s", ptr + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`**p` points to `pink` (i.e. `**p == s[2]`). Incrementing that pointer `(**p) + 1` will make it point to the `i` in `pink`, so `printf` will print `ink`. Elementary. :)

The rule of thumb is that if you feel the need for declaring a triple-pointer, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`*p` gives `ptr[1]`
`**p` gives value stored at `s+2` i,e `"pink"` and it points to character `p`
now `**p+1` gives the string `ink`